# SPARQL MAX(): Can I access a variable that is not in the GROUP BY projection?

Tags: group-by, sparql, rdf

I have a simple activity based model:

```
BASE <https://example.org/>
PREFIX paf: <https://paf.link/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

<1> paf:consistsOf <1/activity/1>, <1/activity/2>, <1/activity/3> .

  <1/activity/1> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-01-01"^^xsd:date .

  <1/activity/2> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-02-02"^^xsd:date .

  <1/activity/3> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-03-03"^^xsd:date .

<2> paf:consistsOf <2/activity/1>, <2/activity/2>, <2/activity/3> .

  <2/activity/1> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-01-01"^^xsd:date .

  <2/activity/2> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-02-02"^^xsd:date .

  <2/activity/3> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-03-03"^^xsd:date .

<3> paf:consistsOf <3/activity/1>, <3/activity/2>, <3/activity/3> .

  <3/activity/1> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-01-01"^^xsd:date .

  <3/activity/2> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-02-02"^^xsd:date .

  <3/activity/3> a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:text "Deutsch"@de, "Französisch"@fr, "Italienisch"@it ;
    paf:hasStartDate "2020-03-03"^^xsd:date .
```

I want to query the most recent activity as only this one matters for what I do next:

```
PREFIX paf: <https://paf.link/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT * 

WHERE {
{
  SELECT ?processIri (max(?activityDate) AS ?latestActivity) WHERE {
    ?processIri paf:consistsOf ?activityIri .

    ?activityIri a paf:Activity ;
      paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
      paf:hasStartDate ?activityDate ;
  } GROUP BY ?processIri
}
  ?processIri paf:consistsOf ?activityIri .
    
  ?activityIri a paf:Activity ;
    paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
    paf:hasStartDate ?latestActivity ;
    paf:text ?text

}
```

This works all fine and I can use that. The only thing that bugs me is that I have to do the join again outside of the inner `SELECT` because I can't put the `?activityIri` in the `GROUP BY` (would not do what I want) and I can't reference it when it's not in the `GROUP BY` projection.

Or would there be another way of doing that?

Comment: that's impossible, you don't have any reference to the activityDate that is the maximum of the group - that would also not work in SQL. Internally only the dates will be collected and then the maximum is chosen . So, in general the answer is "no", your way is the common way.

Comment: but your example allows for some string solution, because the advantage of xsd:date is that you can order it even lexicographically:

Comment: `PREFIX paf: <https://paf.link/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?processIri (strdt(strbefore(?latestFoo, "|"), xsd:date) AS ?latestActivityDate) (iri(strafter(?latestFoo, "|")) AS ?latestActivity) {
SELECT ?processIri (max(?foo) AS ?latestFoo) WHERE {
    ?processIri paf:consistsOf ?activityIri .

    ?activityIri a paf:Activity ;
      paf:activityType <https://paf.link/text> ;
      paf:hasStartDate ?activityDate ;
      BIND(concat(str(?activityDate), "|", str(?activityIri)) AS ?foo)
} GROUP BY ?processIri
}`